# Grails Routing-JMS plugin - Issue while deployment into weblogic

Tags: grails, routes, jms, grails-plugin, grails-2.3

I am using Grails plugin (routing-jms) to enqueue messages into Oracle AQ based queue. It works fine using tomcat but throwing below exception while deploying into Weblogic 10.3 server.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jms.foreign.IgnoreXAResourceImpl
    at oracle.jms.WebLogicHelper.<clinit>(WebLogicHelper.java:57)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConstants.<clinit>(AQjmsConstants.java:310)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnectionFactory.<init>(AQjmsConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(AQjmsFactory.java:160)
    at RoutingJmsGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(RoutingJmsGrailsPlugin.groovy:30)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:755)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1870)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3155)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:487)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
```

Appriciate any help.

Comment: thank you... at least someone bothered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, WebLogic uses a hierarchy of class loaders (see [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/classloading.htm)). It seems like the same class is getting loaded via two different class loaders. And you cannot cast between class loaders, hence the `ClassCastException`.

Re-check your dependencies to exclude any JAR files that are loaded by the server but also by your application.